# How To Convert An Object File To Executable File (C Object File) Using Linker

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation, linker

So I Want To Convert A .c To An .exe File.

The Direct Command I Know Is **gcc -o foo foo.c** (**I Dont Want This Way**)

But Then I Want To Do It Step By Step, Like I Want To Convert The **.c To .S** Using cc Compiler , Then **.S To .o** Using Assembler And Then **.o To .exe** Using Linker.

So I Know How To Convert **.c To .S To .o** But Then I Dont Know The Linker Command

I Only Know Its Something Like :
ld -lc -o foo -ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 foo.o -e main(**Not Sure**, Theres Something I Am Missing,So Please Help Me)

**PS: I Am Using Linux To Compile(Ubuntu Flavor)**

Comment: The assembly step is unnecessary, as you're unlikely to do that in practice. The rest of the steps are usually done using a `Makefile`. Thus, I'd recommend you to familiarize yourself how to use `make` and `Makefile`s, and how to tweak the typical recipes in various situations. It not only helps you understand how the steps occur in practice (as `make` shows each command it runs by default), but you'll soon find that writing `Makefile`s makes it much easier to maintain projects, and that examining other projects' `Makefile`s is quite informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the linker command will be very OS, distribution and platform specific. You can see what GCC makes of it by letting it link with verbose output:

```
gcc -v -o foo foo.o
```

This is the most reliable and fastest way to get the command you need to call. This will include system library search directories, system libraries, and other often not so straightforward options.

I must strongly recommend against calling ld directly, for all the aforementioned reasons, unless you have a very specific use-case that warrants this.